# jQuery .change event not firing on multiple same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code:

```js
$(".imageupload").change(function() {
  alert($(this).attr('data-id'));
  var ID = $(this).attr('data-id');

  if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {

    var image_holder = $("#image-holder" + ID);
    image_holder.empty();

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $("<img />", {
        "src": e.target.result,
        "class": "thumb-image"
      }).appendTo(image_holder);

    }
    image_holder.show();
    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[0]);
  } else {
    alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
  <div id="image-holder1" style="margin-bottom:20px"> </div>
  <input type="file" class="input-file full-width imageupload" data-id="1" name="imageupload1" id="imageupload1" value="" placeholder="">
  <div id="displayimagefield">
    <div id="image-holder2" style="margin-bottom:20px"> </div>
    <input type="file" class="input-file full-width imageupload" data-id="2" name="imageupload2" id="imageupload2" value="" placeholder="">
    <div id="image-holder3" style="margin-bottom:20px"> </div>
    <input type="file" class="input-file full-width imageupload" data-id="3" name="imageupload3" id="imageupload3" value="" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
```

class imageupload is in multiple element. Change event is firing only in data-id="1" not firing anywhere else. How can I resolve this error? Sorry for my weak English.

Comment: it is working fine for me. Please double-check it yourself.

Comment: The code is working fine. I uploaded three images and got three alerts which means the change event triggered for all the threee input change.

Comment: man I am adding field dynamically it is a static field. May be it working fine static field but not working in dynamic field.

Comment: so each time you add more `input`, you need to off all and re-on `("change")` all.

Comment: You need to use event delegation in that case.

Comment: all `inputs` should be put in the same container so that you can use event delegation (on the container) - that's the best way to go.

Comment: I can't understand can you please write answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation for attachine events to dynamically added elements:

```
$("body").on('change','.imageupload',function() {
    //CHANGE EVENT CODE HERE
});
```